# Are UHS SD Cards backwards compatible with existing readers and other hardware?

Tags: sd-card, sdhc, sdxc, uhs

I was shopping for a couple of new memory cards for new cameras this year and noticed that there are some SD cards that are now UHS-1 compatible. I wasn't sure what that really meant so I went looking for more info, and found that UHS stands for Ultra-High Speed and brings newer, faster signaling to SD cards.

Reading the overview at [Secure Digital](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Digital#UHS_Speed_Class) Wikipedia page it isn't clear if the new speeds also come with a guarantee of backwards compatibility. It seems like UHS cards *might* be compatible if the reader/writer also accepts SDXC cards - because they were both defined in version 3.0 of the SD spec, though the signaling (voltage and actual bit transfer) is unique for UHS cards.

Anyone with hands-on experience or links to other articles/vendor pages that might shed light on the subject?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From Lexar's (one of bigger manufacturers of memory cards) FAQ located [here](http://www.lexar.com/support/sd-uhs-i-faqs):

**Can I use an UHS-I card with a SDHC host device?**

> Yes! All SD UHS-I cards can be used with all existing SDXC and SDHC
>   devices (backwards compatible). Note that SDXC UHS-I cards are not
>   compatible with SD or SDHC host devices, only with SDXC host devices.
>   [See the SDXC FAQ for more information](http://www.lexar.com/support/support/sdxc-faqs). Although SD UHS-I cards
>   can be used with all existing SDXC and SDHC devices, if you want to
>   optimize UHS performance, select a device with the UHS-I logo:

Comment: Ah, so 32GB is the cutoff between SDHC and SDXC. A 32GB card will work in SDHC but not 64GB.